# Storing data and making it accessible for users over the internet

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, data-storage, dataprovider

I am a beginner at SQL Server, data storing and web technologies so I don't know how to accomplish what I try to achieve. I am a hobby C# programmer and let's pretend that my program allows you to enter a text, like an article, so its a huge basic `string`.

I am using SQL Server 2014 Express, and I know that it is possible to set it accessible for other users through the internet. Currently I only have small amount of data in it. Because I have read on the internet that it is never a good a idea to store e.g. a huge `string` in it and it's not the way to go.

I've heard that you could save the storage location of that `string` object in the SQL Server database and access it with that.

So that is my question if this way above is a good working solution. So that I save data e.g. in a VM and make this VM accessible for the internet with user identification and the SQL Server database gives you the information to connect to the VM's data and the information about the storage location of the requested object. I want users to be able to up- and download data from other users but all the data is in one public place. (like a VM on my pc or a different pc)

As I am a student, I don't have money for a web service or web server but I am curious about your opinion to the whole subject. I don't want any code from you, just the idea about the way of global data storing/sharing these days.

Comment: Opinion based questions are not valid questions, please read the guidelines for posting

Comment: This isnt meant about an opinion, i just dont know what a good way is how to do this and if that what i want to try is even possible. All i want are facts about common used techniques. E.g. how they are called that i can teach it myself, i just dont want to start working on a project based on a bad or even old concept/idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server is a database so yes, it can hold information (even a huge string which would be a data type called `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)` depending on if you need it to hold other languages. If you are putting the code on a web server and then a SQL Server in a VM though I wouldn't give permission to the VM to the internet, I would just give it permission to access the web site and have the website put/pull information from the database. You might want to look into something like SQLite though - SQL Server could be overkill if you are only looking to store one string.

SQLite is free so you wouldn't have to pay for it. Pretty much any database can store images as a binary object so you can do that in SQL Server or SQLite. A tutorial for SQLite is here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196618/C-SQLite-Storing-Images

MySQL is another option - it really just depends on how robust you need the server and what you are attempting to do with your web code as to what would be the best fit.

Comment: `string` was just meant to be a basic example and as i said i dont want any web services i have to pay for. SQLite is another option but how about storing and accessing images?

Comment: If you are saying you want to grant internet access to the database directly and not have any sort of programming to handle the information I would really stress that this is almost (never?) done in the real world is a really bad idea.  I would strongly suggest you use some kind of web based code to present that information.

Comment: @ElementZero, SQL Server Express Edition is also free.

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes I know. I assume he already knew that since he said he was already using it so I didn't mentioned it but you are right, I suppose I should have just made this clear. It's just that SQL Express has some limitations that could be overcome by SQLite or MySQL Community so I'm offering different options since he says he has no money to pay for it. Again it depends on what he wants to do (the full extent of which he hasn't specified).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but i will try to explain my requirements in a short basic way with an example. I have a C# appilcation where you can enter and save text and you should be able to upload this and local images. What is a good way where to upload those and access them from the internet for free? Just storing in a local db and grant the db access through the internet? Setting up a local serve with another pc and granting this one internet access and through the application i can connect to this home server? What would you suggest?

Comment: Again I would not suggest giving the internet direct access to the database. You would set up the application to save images to the database then you should be setting up a website and have that web site pull the images down from the database and display them.  Both the database and the web site can be on the same server though I would typically recommend they are separate.

Comment: Actually I think I might have just figured out what you are meaning.  Do you mean the application needs to save images to the database from different machine all over the internet?  In that case yes - you should have a web service that handle the saving of images from the client application to your database.  You shouldn't have the application save directly over the internet into the database.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't make any VM accessible to other people on the internet ever, unless it was behind some sort of VPN and protected appropriately and those people were part of your organization. What you are looking to do is set up an API where users can register, obtain a valid API token then make requests for certain information that could be in your database.

If you are learning, a PHP REST API (or any REST API in a language you like) in conjunction with MySQL is usually a good place to start with lots of documentation. You can do this with frameworks like laravel or codeigniter.

If you want to stick with Microsoft's SQL server you will probably run into some licensing issues should you ever expand. Beyond that, I am not too familiar with asp.net / vb.net (microsoft's frameworks)

Best of luck on your searches.

Comment: Thank you, i will have a look at that and see if this is helpful for my project.